# What does this black bar represent in my iPod's Storage Capacity Indicator?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ipod, storage

I was recently going through my (2nd Gen) iPod Touch's storage settings in the most recent version of iTunes and noticed that there is a small gray/black bar next to the "Other" storage section. I highly doubt that this is simply a drop shadow as other depictions of this graph do not feature such a bar.

**What does this small bar represent?**

[image: The black bar is outlined in red.]

*Note: The small bar is outlined in red.*

Comment: For what it's worth, I have over 4,000 notes on this iPod from different papers/assignments but otherwise, it is a fairly typical iPod.

Answer (score 1):

To my belief, that indeed *is* actually just a drop shadow. Since you're actually not on the newest version of iTunes, I can't verify that, since it looks different now, but here are a few photos:

---

[image]

iTunes 12 (latest version)

---

[image]

Version that looks the same as yours also showing shadow

---

[image]

Older version also displaying drop shadow

---

With that said, I could still be wrong. [Check and make sure it isn't any of these categories:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201656)

- Audio: Songs, audio podcasts, audiobooks, voice memos, and ringtones
- Video: Movies, music videos, and TV shows
- Photos: Camera Roll content, Photo Stream, and Photo Library
- Apps: Installed apps
- Books: iBooks books and PDF files
- Documents & Data: Safari Offline Reading List, files created within apps, and app content like contacts, calendars, messages, and emails (and their attachments)
- Other:
  Settings, Siri voices, system data, and cached files